# Brightness control won't work on a Samsung NF208

Tags: 11.04, hardware, brightness, samsung

I just installed ubuntu 11.04 on my samsung NF208 and at first it worked just fine, the fn key was all alright except the fn+f9 (I guess that's normal as it opens up a samsung-specific software). Yesterday I updated my ubuntu and after I rebooted the system, the brightness control key (fn + up/down) just won't work. It does display the brightness indicator and the indicator itself is changing when I press the fn + up/down, but the display won't change a bit.
please help me, I'm new to this ubuntu thing :)

p.s
I experienced same thing when I use win7 after I installed an update for Intel Graphic Driver. I managed to rollback the driver and it worked again. Do I get the same problem here in ubuntu? then how can I rollback the driver in ubuntu? or is it a totally different problem?

thanks for your concern.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You cound try to downgrade the driver package. Did you install the driver from the repositories? If yes you can downgrade a package using:

```
sudo apt-get install package=version
```

I think you are looking for the package xserver-xorg-video-intel. To find out your current version, use

```
dpkg -s xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Information on the package can be found [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/oneiric/xserver-xorg-video-intel).